# taskdef A class needed by class org.apache.jasper.JspC cannot be found: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.JspC

Tags: java, tomcat, ant

Hi I am getting the error `taskdef A class needed by class org.apache.jasper.JspC cannot be found: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.JspC` when I tried to build the build.xml file. can anyone please give me a solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to my ant classpath:

```
/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but it was a long time ago and unfortunately my memory has become quite foggy on the subject.

As I recall, you need to start ANT with the `-lib` command line switch and have it point to some jar files that are needed by Jasper's JSP compiler. Again, I don't remember exactly which ones, but I think the JDK's `tools.jar` was one of them, as well as all the jars with `jasper` in the names, and `commons-logging.jar` and `commons-el.jar`. You'll have to do some experimenting :).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the required Jasper libraries in your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

That is a relatively high level exception.  If you would like to know more detail about what is missing from your classpath, you can run `ant` with the `-verbose` flag on the commandline.

It would be good to see the build.xml that you are using.  [Apache has put an example out here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/jasper-howto.html#Web%20Application%20Compilation), which sounds similar to what you are using.  If so, it requires that you specify some vars.

For this example Apache suggests:

> The following command line can be used to run the script (replacing the tokens with the Tomcat base path and the path to the webapp which should be precompiled):

```
$ANT_HOME/bin/ant -Dtomcat.home=<$TOMCAT_HOME> -Dwebapp.path=<$WEBAPP_PATH>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error in eclipse "taskdef A class needed by class org.apache.jasper.JspC cannot be found: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.JspC",

jasper-compiler.jar consists of "org.apache.jasper.JspC", so please copy the commons-collections.jar in the same dirctory.

jasper-compiler.jar will be in C:\jboss-4.0.2\server\default\deploy\jbossweb-tomcat55.sar.

Hope it will resolve the issue.